# How can I change the useState value according to the condition when the function is executed in React native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I created a useState function in an array object called box.

The values ​​are as follows.

```
const [box, setBox] = useState([
{name: "coffee", placeId: 257, productCode: "INSECT3"}
{name: "tea", placeId: 258, productCode: "INSECT3"}
{name: "coke", placeId: 259, productCode: "INSECT3"}
{name: "fanta", placeId: 260, productCode: "INSECT3"}
])
```

Also I have an array object called hi[0].children.

```
hi[0].children = [
    {placeId: 257}
    {placeId: 258}
]
```

What I want to do is when the onChangeInnerPicker function is triggered, if the placeId of hi[0].children and the placeId of the box are the same, I want to change the productCode of the box with the same placeId to the prodata that is received as an argument.

My whole code is like this.

When hi[0].children and box's placeId values ​​are equal to 257 and 258, and the prodata value input as an argument is "INSECT4", the answer I want is this.

```
const [box, setBox] = useState([
{name: "coffee", placeId: 257, productCode: "INSECT4"}
{name: "tea", placeId: 258, productCode: "INSECT4"}
{name: "coke", placeId: 259, productCode: "INSECT3"}
{name: "fanta", placeId: 260, productCode: "INSECT3"}
])
```

However, when I run my code, it enters a completely different place, rather than replacing the matching value in the corresponding placeId. like this

```
const [box, setBox] = useState([
{name: "coffee", placeId: 257, productCode: "INSECT4"}
{name: "tea", placeId: 258, productCode: "INSECT4"}
{name: "coke", placeId: 259, productCode: "INSECT3"}
{name: "fanta", placeId: 260, productCode: "INSECT3"}
productCode: "INSECT4"
])
```

this is my whole code

```
    const [box, setBox] = useState([
    {name: "coffee", placeId: 257, productCode: "INSECT3"}
    {name: "tea", placeId: 258, productCode: "INSECT3"}
    {name: "coke", placeId: 259, productCode: "INSECT3"}
    {name: "fanta", placeId: 260, productCode: "INSECT3"}
    ])

hi[0].children = [
    {placeId: 257}
    {placeId: 258}
]



const onChangeInnerPicker = (prodata) => {


hi[0].children.map((v) => {
    box.map((item) => {
        if (v.placeId === item.placeId) {
            console.log("item.placeId:", item.placeId)    // 257, 258
            console.log("prodata:", prodata);     // prodata : "INSECT4" 
             setBox({ ...box, [productCode]: prodata })
        }
    })
})

}
```

so How can i fix my code?

Comment: Check the `setBox` call. you're passing an object to the state updater, when your state is actually an array.
Maybe what you meant was to pass a function instead? so that you could update the state properly

Comment: @chimera  yes but how can i do that? ....

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting your handler this is what I would suggest

```js
const onChangeInnerPicker = (prodata) => {
  setBox((prevState) => {
    return prevState.map((b) => {
      if (hi[0].children.inludes(b.placeId))
        return { ...b, productCode: prodata };
      return b;
    });
  });
};
```

First of all, rather than using the state values I prefer doing all this in a state updater function (pass a function to `setState` rather than a value). That way you can get the previous state as a parameter and work with it safely within that function. Note you should not mutate state there as you should not anywhere else.

Given that you have the list of the `placeId`s of where you want to replace the values you can use that list as a whitelist of which elements in the array to update. That way whenever we find one of the elements that meet that condition we map the value to your `prodata`

This might be helpful:
https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state